# Correct way to use Hibernate Persistence and Validation together

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-validator

I have a situation using hibernate persistence with hibernate validations and although I've thought of a few hack-ish approaches, I don't know the best way to solve this problem using hibernate persistence and validation.

Simply put, I have a User object and I want to persist it. But before I persist it I want to validate it. Pretty standard stuff.

Now, a User object has a password and we have rules about valid passwords. Eg: minimum of 8 characters, include at least 1 number, etc...I want to validate these things.

But when I persist I need to encrypt/salt/hash the password. But after I do the salting/hashing there is obviously no reasonably way to do the above validations on the password.

So, I thought I could use the @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations for this. My thought was in the User class I have a method called onCreate(). I tagged it with @PrePersist and I do something like this (I have something similar for onUpdate()):

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    encryptPassword();
}
```

I thought that when I call entityManager.persist() it would first call the validations, then call onCreate() and then persist. So the validations would validate the original, non-salted/hashed password. And the salting/hashing would happen later.

When I ran my tests and debugged though, I found that methods tagged with @PrePersist get called before validations run meaning I can't validate my password anymore.

How do I hook the salting/hashing of the password correctly into the entityManager.persist() lifecycle so that I can validate correctly and after that salt and hash and finally persist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two bean properties, one for persistence and the other for validation / conversion. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@MyCustomConstraint(...)
public class User implements Serializable {

    // place persistence annotations here, for example
    @Lob @Column(...)
    private byte[] hashedPassword;
    // place validation constraints here, for example
    @Size(min = 8, max = 16)
    @Transient
    private String password;

    public byte[] getHashedPassword() {
        return this.hashedPassword;
    }

    protected void setHashedPassword(byte[] hashedPassword) {
        this.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        this.setHashedPassword(this.hashAndSaltMyPassword(this.password));
    }

    protected String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    protected byte[] hashAndSaltMyPassword(String password) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense but limits my ability to validate the password. I have a custom password validator I put on the class level. It's class level because I must do cross-field validation. Specifically, I need to validate the password is not the same as the username. Because of this I believe I need to have a @Transient password field that stores the plaintext password for validation in my custom validator. If I could just use simple field level annotations your suggestion would work fine. Any thoughts on how to achieve what you've described with a class level validation annotation?

Comment: Well, you've already described your answer, but I edited the answer anyway. To summarize, store the plaintext password in a `@Transient` field, add the class level constraint, and write a protected getter. I'd suggest defining your validator in the same package.

Comment: Right, thanks for that. I managed to do this without the need for a protected version of getPassword(). If plaintext pwd is not null return the plaintext pwd (it will only be null when creating a new user or changing the pwd). If plaintext pwd is null then return the hashed version. And yeah I considered putting validators in the same package, but was hoping not to pollute the entity package space, but more and more it seems that this might be the right thing to do given the tight coupling of entities and their validators.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Hopefully will this will be useful to others as well. I'm marking this as the correct answer as indeed this is what I did with success.